# Can I take a wrapped gift of skin care products with me on the airplane?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage

It's wrapped and I am not sure about the sizes, all I know is that it's a collection of men grooming products. I dont even have the receipt.

Would it be a problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't risk this in your hand luggage. If the containers are bigger than 100ml you'll have to throw them away at airport security.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How would you answer the following question?

> Are you aware of all the contents of your bags?

Technically, you should not carry this in any of your bags (checked or not), because you don't know what it is. However, if you trust the person who packed or wrapped this, then you should be fine.

Depending on where you are flying, you may or may not be able to carry liquid or gel products over a certain size. And even if you are, you may need to place the products in a clear plastic bag for security inspection. If it's already wrapped, you're probably not going to be able to do that without completely unwrapping it first.

If you send this through the X-ray scanner, they will notice that it contains liquid or gels (if indeed it does), and then will have a lot of further questions for you to answer.

Answer (score 6):

You will absolutely not be able to take this on your hand luggage:

1. Its wrapped, the security personnel will ask you to open it.
2. If its more than 100ml, the security personnel will discard it.

So, if you want to make sure you receive this item, put it in your checked luggage.

Comment: Checked luggage is never sure to arrive, in particular not to arrive on-time.  If it's an extremely pricey gift I would not put it in checked luggage.  Better to unwrap it and put it in a transparent bag through security, then rewrap it after the flight.  Or take the train.

Comment: @gerrit That's not exactly true ... I've been flying back and forward trough Europe every month for the past 4 years. So far i only didn't get my luggage once. Aside the extra half an hour i had to spend at the airport to sign forms and what not, i got it the next day delivered to my house (which saved me dragging it around the city from the airport to the coach station)

Comment: @ИвоНедев I think it happened at least 5 times to my wife in the past 5 years of flying 5–10 times per year, including one occasion where it took over three weeks before her luggage arrived.  Are your flights typically direct?  Hers normally include transfers, which significantly increases the risk of delayed or lost luggage.

Comment: @gerrit Usually a spend half a day at German airports between my connections. I guess Lufthansa just has it better ...

Comment: In my 10+ years of flying (started when going to boarding school) - I have had my luggage lost _once_ and the majority of my travel is connections/transfers/transit.  My luggage was once delayed - it arrived on the next flight. That's about it. I guess I'm lucky.

Comment: It looks like that within the US, there are [between 1 and 8 reports of lost or delayed luggage per 1000 passengers](http://airconsumer.ost.dot.gov/reports/2012/September/2012SeptATCR.PDF), with an average of 3.5.  Suppose that means 24 hours late (1 flight per day?) you may consider if you want to risk a 0.35% chance of delayed luggage (lost is much lower).  Not sure why my personal experience has a far higher rate than this.

Comment: @gerrit if distribution was equal and all the lost luggage victims experienced only one occurance, they still have 100% more occurrences than the non-victims. Distribution is never equal and never fair. Roll the dice again my friend!